# Is $1992! - 1$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the factorials, defined inductively by $1! = 0! = 1$ and $n! = n\cdot(n-1)!$ for $n \geq 2$.

> Question: Is $1992!-1$ a prime number?

The question is from a book, maybe is contest math problem. Now I think 1992 is especial?

Comment: Is this contest-math? If so, please add the tag.

Comment: [related](https://oeis.org/A002982)

Comment: it's from a book,maybe is contest math problem,Now I think $1992$ is especial?

Comment: You may interested in [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007298?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) which determines all primes of the form $n! \pm 1$ up to $10^{1000}$, in particular.

Comment: There are two deleted answers that show that $1992! +1$ can be shown not to be prime using Wilson's theorem and the fact that $1993$ is prime (which can be checked with reasonable effort). Could you please clarify, and double check, where exactly this problem comes from. It is of course trivial to answer using current computational technology but this can be hardly the point of this question.

Comment: In addition to @quid's advice, perhaps you could add the title and author(s) of the book, and the location in the book (page number) where it is found.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. The smallest prime factors are $3449$ and $8627$ (found with Mathematica).

For what it's worth:

$$
\{n\in\mathbb{N}:2\le n\le2000\text{ and }n!-1\text{ is prime }\}=\\\{3,4,6,7,12,14,30,32,33,38,94,166,324,379,469,546,974,1963\}
$$

Should have thought of checking OEIS. This is sequence [A002982](https://oeis.org/A002982)

Comment: Is it possible to find answer without CAS?

Comment: I think this is a comment not an answer even if it technically answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I do not know of a theoretical argument to show it is not prime. Of course this does not mean that it does not exist.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, me too. But what about numbers $n!-1$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza that's not an easy problem. At the moment I consider it as the most likely scenario that the intended solution is actually the one on two deleted answers, which just does not work. (Maybe a typo in the question.)

Comment: Just a "curious note": Mathematica finds no other prime factors less than $1\,000\,000$. Also, should really $n=3$ be in your list? Or is there a small misprint ($(n-1)!$ should perhaps be $n!$)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Other prime factors have to be grater than $2\,038\,074\,743$.