# Is $a=\frac{1992!-1}{3449\times 8627}$ a prime number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Is $a=\dfrac{1992!-1}{3449\times 8627}$ a prime number ?
This is a natural follow-up to that recent
MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375708/is-1992-1-prime?newsletter=1&nlcode=368873|f177)

We know that $a$ has $5702$ digits and no prime divisor $<10^6$.

Comment: Can you please verify that $a$ has 5701 digits? I get 5702.

Comment: Well, you only have about $10^{2851}-10^6$ factors left to try... You can skip $2/3$ of them (testing only those which are adjacent to multiples of $6$), so that leaves you with around $10^{2850}$ factors left to try... Good luck :)

Comment: I tried that yesterday, and Mathematica said it was not a prime.

Comment: @whythagoras: i can confirm the number of digits. i measured it with 
    len(str(a))    in python and got 5702, so 5701 is correct (one character is for the L in python)

Comment: @supinf Well [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1992%21-1%7D%7B3449%5Ctimes+8627%7D) seems to say 5072

Comment: @Surb and whytagoras: sorry i am wrong about the number of digits, i made a mistake with python. I blame my confirmation bias

Comment: @wythagoras and Surb : corrected, thanks

Comment: In that question it was verified that there are no prime factors smaller than $2038074743$.

Comment: If it is not prime, someone <i>might</i> be able to produce a factor for you.  If it is prime, you'll never know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $\dfrac{1992!-1}{3449\times 8627}$ is divisible by $86544733151681393$, found using [GMP-ECM](http://ecm.gforge.inria.fr/).

Moreover, $\dfrac{1992!-1}{3449 \times 8627 \times 86544733151681393}$ is also not prime; it fails the [Fermat Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) for bases $a \in \{2,3,5,7\}$, checked with [OpenPFGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/).

Answer (score 2):

I just ran a Rabin-Miller test on that number and I got the result "False" (i.e. it is NOT a prime number). If you want to know the divisors in addition to what you asked then I don't think that is computationally easy.

```
>>> rabinmiller(a,1)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Maple also says no:

```
is((factorial(1992)-1)/(3449*8627), prime);
```

$$\it{false}$$

Comment: This is not an answer, although it would be a reasonable comment to the main question.